# $S:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ , $S(x,y)=x+y$ is continuous.

Tags: real-analysis

Prove: $S:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ , $S(x,y)=x+y$ is continuous.

My attempt:

$d((x,y),(a,b)) = d(x,a) + d(y,b)$

Let $\epsilon >0$.

I need to prove:
$d(x+y,a+b) < \epsilon$. If the following inequality is valid:
$d(x+y,a+b) \leq d(x,a) + d(y,b)$, then I can choose $\delta=\epsilon$.
But I can't verify that inequality.

Can someone please show me how to verify or if it is false show a counter-example?

I'm starting to think that this proof isn't that simple, probably the inequality I used is false. 
Thanks.

EDIT:

Please verify if this is correct:

Let $\delta = \epsilon$

$d(x+y,a+b) = |x+y-(a+b)| = |x+y-a-b| \leq |x-a| + |y-b| < \delta = \epsilon$

Comment: Are you intending to use the standard Euclidean metric on $\mathbb R^2$?

Comment: this is triangle inequality, which is a property of a metric, so it seems correct.

Comment: Yes, I was supposed to but didn't think of that. I edited my attempt.

Comment: If you're using the standard Euclidean metric on $\mathbb{R}^2$, then shouldn't your distance function be $$d_{\mathbb{R}^2}((x,y),(a,b)) = \sqrt{(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2} = \sqrt{d_{\mathbb{R}}(x,a)^2+d_{\mathbb{R}}(y,b)^2}$$?

Comment: Yes! I made a mistake and used the 1-dimensional euclidean metric, which doesn't make sense. I'm going to try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It almost seems like you have it backwards. You should be fixing $\epsilon$ first and then finding a $\delta$ which is sufficiently small. You have correctly come to the inequality:

$$d(S(x,y),S(a,b))=d(x+y,a+b) \leq |x-a| + |y-b|$$

What we want to ensure is that for a given $\epsilon$, there exists a sufficiently small $\delta$. In other words, for *any chosen* $\epsilon$, can we choose a $\delta$ such that 
$$d((x,y),(a,b)) < \delta \quad \Rightarrow \quad |x-a| + |y-b| < \epsilon \quad ?$$
For a start, let's evaluate $d((x,y),(a,b))$:
$$d((x,y),(a,b)) = \sqrt{(x-a)^2 + (a-b)^2}$$
Note that this is greater than or equal to either $|x-a|$ or $|x-b|$. So
$$2 \cdot d((x,y),(a,b)) \geq |x-a| + |y-b|$$
$$2 \cdot d((x,y),(a,b)) \geq d(S(x,y),S(a,b))$$
Which means that for a given $\epsilon$, we can ensure that the right hand side is strictly less than it by setting
$$d((x,y),(a,b)) < \epsilon / 2$$
And so for a given $\epsilon$, the largest $\delta$ which will work in general is $\epsilon / 2$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I understood all you did. In my attempt when I said $ \delta = \epsilon$ I was in fact trying to find $\delta$, but in my (wrong) proof I found $\delta$ to be equal to the  $\epsilon>0$ previously declared.

Comment: @Alnitak - I'm happy it helped you. Generally, we try and look for an inequality between the two metrics as was done here. When you have this inequality, you can easily find an expression for $\delta$ given $\epsilon$.